# How to output selected column values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a single model `Person` there is an address information. But since we are not separating this yet to another table. I would like to only query the address information out of `Person` table. Would it be possible using `hybrid_property` If not what else do I need to achieve this stuff?

**I wanna avoid this one:**

```
db.session.query(Person.id, Person.address_secret_id, Person.address_name).get(pk)
```

**The model**

```
class Person(db.Model):
    # some lengthy information

    # address
    address_secret_id = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=True)
    address_name = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def address(self):
       # I never tested this but i know this is wrong.
       return self.id + self.address_secret_id + self.address_name
```

**Usage:**

```
db.session.query(Person.address).get(pk)
```

Expected Output:

```
{id: 1, address_secret_id: xxxx, address_name: 'forgetmeland'}
```

How can I achieve an output that is only retrieving the desired field? It doesn't need to be dict or tuple as long as Im getting what is needed.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid typing `db.session.query(Person.id, Person.address_secret_id, Person.address_name)`?

Comment: The answer to your title is "yes". The rest is unclear. Why would you expect a dictionary as output? How come the components are separated in the dictionary, though you're trying to query the hybrid that combines them?

Comment: @SuperShoot true!

Comment: @IljaEverilä sorry for not making it clear. That is only an example. It could be any other type as long as im getting only the same fields

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to avoid having to type `db.session.query(Person.id, Person.address_secret_id, Person.address_name)`, just add an `address_details` property on the person model.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    # some lengthy information

    # address
    address_secret_id = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=True)
    address_name = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=True)

    @property
    def address_details(self):
        keys = ('id', 'address_secret_id', 'address_name')
        return {k: getattr(self, k) for k in in keys}
```

Probably less lines of code than trying to use some sort of hybrid query, and still just the one trip to the database.

Query would be:

`Person.query.get(1).address_details`

Comment: Is there no other way in query() level?

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to avoid it.

Comment: I see so there is no otherway in doing this using hybrid_property

Comment: There might be, but what would be the advantage of adding the complexity?

Comment: actually in the real model there are a lot of field that is need to be refactored. So for the time being we need to come up with a temporary solution. and that is not costly in sql level